# What name should have method which returns number of nested objects?

Tags: java, naming-conventions, api-design

Suppose we have classes Gallery and Image. There can be many images in one gallery.

Gallery should have some method which returns number of nested images. My suggestions:

```
int getImagesCount ();

int countImages ();

int imagesCount ();
```

I saw examples of each of these 3 suggestions in different APIs (of course with another noun or even without it, like method `size ()` in Collections API).

What would you prefer and why? (One of my thoughts against `countImages ()` is that this name can make user think that this method does some complex calculations.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion:

```
public interface Gallery {

    int getNumberOfImages();

    //...
}
```

I agree, that `countXX()` leads to the impression, that calling this method triggers some sort of calculation. So I wouldn't use it here as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would rule out `countImages ()` too, for the same reason.

Other than that, if there is a more or less consistent naming convention in the codebase `Gallery` belongs to, I would recommend adhering to it. In absence of a clear project convention, I personally would lean towards `size()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are thinking of having one method that returns the size, and another one that returns the nth element, my recommendation in general: **Don't do it! Use the power of the collections api!**: create a method that returns a `List<Image>`.
That way the user of the API can more easily do things like iterating over the images (using the enhanced for-loop instead of having to juggle with indices), sorting them, combining them in other collections,...

It is really easy to implement:

- If the images are internally already represented as a list, you can just return that (optionally wrapped with Collections.unmodifiableList).
- And even if you don't store them as a list, exposing them as `List<Image>` is as easy as writing a small subclass of `AbstractList` by just overriding `size()` and `get(int)`, the two methods you were going to implement anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `size()` is that it's not necessarily clear whether you're returning the number of elements (images in this case) or the size in bytes/kilobytes/megabytes of the collection. For the same reason, I tend to prefer `getImageDimensions()` to `getImageSize()`. In your case, I like `countImages()` because it's clear and concise, but it doesn't follow naming conventions if for example, there are methods like `getImage(int)`. Therefore, I will have to go with `int getImagesCount()` or better, `int getNumberOfImages()` or `int getNumImages()`

Comment: Personally it would have never come to my mind that `size()` for a collection-like object could return the size of its memory footprint :-o To me this would be very much against Java interface conventions.

Comment: Yes, for a Java collection, this would be true. But I would never implement a `size()` method when my class doesn't derive from `java.util.Collection`.

Comment: Remember also, that in this specific example, a gallery is a collection of files as much as of images, so it's sort of like saying `aDirectory.size()`, which _could_ easily mean the size in bytes, but also a count of files in the directory. Thus my gut feeling that `something.size()` is ambiguous, especially in this case.